# Determine the interval in which the solution is defined

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the solution of the following initial value problem or general solution in explicit form.Determine(at least approximately) the interal in which the solution is defined.

$$y' \ = \ \frac{3x^2-e^x}{2y-5} ,y(0)=1 \ . $$

I solved it and get  $ \ y = \frac{5}{2} \pm \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{25-4(e^x-x^3-3)} \ . $ How the interval can be found?

Comment: I checked it,its an explicit solution

Answer (score 0):

Very simple, $x\in\mathbb{C}$ .